# MySQL: Server does not exist or connection refused

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i have a MySQL database that´s run under localhost:3306. With a program like sequel pro i can connect without any problems to the database.

If i try to connect these database in asp .net core and Dapper with the connections string:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=test;User ID=admin;Password=secret;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

i get the following error msg:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Server does not exist or connection refused.
```

and i don´t know why.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the MySQL ODBC connector? https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Comment: Thanks, DaSourcerer told me before. That was the solution. @all thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think your connection string is [underspecified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#Common%20Connection%20String%20Settings) in that it lacks a portnumber. 3306 is [specific to MySQL](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=3306), so it has to be explicitly stated as follows:

```
connectionString="Server=tcp:.,3306;Database=test..."
```

Comment: now i get this error: System.Exception: Unknown packet type 74

Comment: Ok, then the connector doesn't know how to handle MySQL. Can you try to use the MySQL-specific connector from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422456/using-mysql-data-mysqlclient-is-not-working)?